# Customize labels with Plotly

Tags: python, pandas, cluster-analysis, plotly, k-means

I am trying to customize the data labels which appear when hovering:
[image]
Here is the code giving me the output above:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go

# Create random data
labels = ['A', 'B', 'C']
N = 20
df = pd.DataFrame(index = range(N))
standardized_cols = []

for col in labels:
    df[col] = np.random.randn(N)
    standardized_colname  =  col + "_standardized"
    standardized_cols.append(standardized_colname)
    df[standardized_colname] = (df[col]-df[col].mean())/df[col].std()

# Cluster
c = KMeans(n_clusters=3, random_state=1).fit(df[standardized_cols]).labels_

# Plot
trace = go.Scatter3d(
    x=df.A_standardized,
    y=df.B_standardized,
    z=df.C_standardized,

    mode='markers',
    marker=dict(
        size=5,
        color=c,              
        colorscale='Viridis',   
    ),
    name= 'test',
    text= c
)

data = [trace]

fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
iplot(fig)
```

My data:
[image]]

The chart shows me clustering of the standardized columns.
But when hovering over the data I'd like to see the not standardized data in the lable, i.e.something like

```
A: 0,999
B: 0,565
C: 0,765
Cluster: 2
```

I experimented but could not figure out how to achieve this. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do some list comprehension and add whatever columns you want to `text` see sample below (note, I am plotting offline):

```
# data
np.random.seed(1)
labels = ['A', 'B', 'C']
N = 20
df = pd.DataFrame(index = range(N))
standardized_cols = []

for col in labels:
    df[col] = np.random.randn(N)
    standardized_colname  =  col + "_standardized"
    standardized_cols.append(standardized_colname)
    df[standardized_colname] = (df[col]-df[col].mean())/df[col].std()

c = KMeans(n_clusters=3, random_state=1).fit(df[standardized_cols]).labels_
```

plot:

```
import plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go


trace = go.Scatter3d(
    x=df.A_standardized,
    y=df.B_standardized,
    z=df.C_standardized,

    mode='markers',
    marker=dict(
        size=5,
        color=c,              
        colorscale='Viridis',   
    ),
    name= 'test',

    # list comprehension to add text on hover
    text= [f"A: {a}<br>B: {b}<br>C: {c}" for a,b,c in list(zip(df['A'], df['B'], df['C']))],
    # if you do not want to display x,y,z
    # hoverinfo='text'


)


layout = dict(title = 'TEST',)

data = [trace]
fig = dict(data=data, layout=layout)

py.offline.plot(fig, filename = 'stackTest.html')
```

[image]

you can modify the list comprehension to display whatever you want

if you do not want to display `x,y,z` then add `hoverinfo='text'`

Comment: The data on hover is index 3 when `np.random.seed(1)`

Comment: I think `import plotly.figure_factory as ff` is obsolete here

Comment: @zinyosrim it is, sorry about that...I grabbed the imports from another `plotly` graph I was working on earlier this week.